# How to read array from PHP (JSON) and fill few inputs via JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am building small web app, and I want to:

- read var from user input
- pass this var to PHP via AJAX when the user clicks on link
- receive array (JSON)
- parse the array and fill them into two input values

And the last action is difficult for me.

Simple example PHP:

```
<?php
$array = array("name" => "James", "surname" => "Bond");
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

and my HTML is something like:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#click_me").click(function(){
                $.post('127.0.0.1/read_from_php/', {
                    my_var : $("#my_var").val()
                }, function(data) {
                    //how to read and parse JSON from PHP here
                    //and put name and surname as a input value below:
                    $('#name').val(data);
                    $('#surname').val(data);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

<input type="text" id="my_var" name="my_var" value="">
<a href="#" id="click_me">Click to read from PHP</a>

<div id="my_div">.. loading ..
   <input type="text" name="name"    id="name"    value="name"/>
   <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" value="surname"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert the json string into an object:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#click_me").click(function(){
            $.post('127.0.0.1/read_from_php/', {
                my_var : $("#my_var").val()
            }, function(data) {
                var person = JSON.parse(data);
                $('#name').val(person.name);
                $('#surname').val(person.surname);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Or, alternatively maybe you could change to [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) as it will already handle the parsing internally.

Comment: Glad to help, don't forget to flag the answer to help others. :P

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json_data);
```

After that, you can use it as you want.
obj.name, obj.surname

Answer (score 0):

1. Set correct content type headers, when rendering JSON with PHP

   ```
   <?php
   $array = array("name" => "James", "surname" => "Bond");
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   echo json_encode($array);
   ?>
   ```
2. Add a data-type to `jQuery.post` call, it will tell jQuery to expect JSON in response. This should allow you to directly access the data object without any additional decoding calls, read this doc for more info http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

   ```
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#click_me").click(function(){
               $.post(
                   '127.0.0.1/read_from_php/',
                   {
                       my_var : $("#my_var").val()
                   },
                   function(data) {
                       //how to read and parse JSON from PHP here
                       //and put name and surname as a input value below:
                       $('#name').val(data.name);
                       $('#surname').val(data.surname);
                   },
                   'json'
               );
           });
       });
   </script>
   ```